# How to go from degital attribute to categorical one in decision trees

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, decision-tree, entropy

Assuming that we have a degital attribute f ( f values in R, interval of reals ). I want to write an algorithm that finds the threshold value v for which, the boolean attribute f>v will have the minimum entropy value possible.

Would you please help me do it.

Comment: You have described what `rpart` does (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rpart/versions/4.1-11/topics/rpart).

Comment: I'm not searching for a pre-implemented function to do it, I want to understand the way of thinking and write it by myself